# Which is the best way call a controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs. Please explain which is the best way or difference between calling controller.

```
app.controller**("HeadCn", ['$scope','$sce',function($scope,$sce)** {
$scope.title="title";
}]);

app.controller**("HeadCn", function($scope,$sce)**{
$scope.title="title 1";
});
```

I am not native in English please excuse me.

Comment: You could take a look at john papa's styleguide, an angular bible ! https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way is the best and recommended way to use. Both form is same but difference will create during minfication. If you don't follow the step1 , minification will break your code.

Uglify Version of your 1st code

```
myApp.controller("myAppController",["$scope",'$sce',function(o,a){}])
```

Uglify Version of your 2nd code

```
myApp.controller("myAppController",function(o,a){})
```

If you follow step 1 , Angular will find definition of `o` from injection.

But if you follow step 2 , Angular won't find definition of `o` from any source.